# Null or Not Null

Tags: java

I know that in Java a variable can be `null` or not `null`. So I want to ask that is there any other possibility?

```
String abc = null; //or a value or anything or any other thing I don't know like undefined vs
if (abc == null) {
    System.out.println("IF");
} else if (abc != null) {
    System.out.println("ELSE IF");
}
```

In that code is there any need to insert an `else` branch? Like this:

```
String abc = null; //or a value or anything
if (abc == null) {
    System.out.println("IF");
} else if (abc != null) {
    System.out.println("ELSE IF");
} else {
    //any possibility to come here ???
}
```

Comment: Think of null as 0. You're checking: is this thing zero? And then: is this thing something other than zero? Can you think of a case that is not covered?

Comment: It would be clearer to have a simple `if/else` instead of `if/elseif`.

Comment: Why you need `else if` when there is only two possibilities either `null` or `not null`. Just use `if..else`

Comment: what else do you think it would be other than one or the other? since the `==` and `!=` are boolean operators why do you even think it could be anything else? there is `true`, `false` there is no `maybe`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that in java a variable can be null or not null.

In fact that is not correct:

```
int test = null;  // Compilation error
if (test == null) // Compilation error
```

Variables whose type is a primitive type *cannot* be `null` and cannot be compared with null.

Only variables whose type is a reference type (i.e. a class type or an array type) can have `null` as a value.

> So ı want to ask that is there any other possibility

Assuming you are talking about reference types, then No.

But that is a logical tautology.  If any variable can have `null` as a value, then its value either is `null` ... or it isn't `null`.

And in general<sup>1</sup>, for any type `T`, `t` is a variable of type `T` and `v` is an value of type `T` then

```
 (t != V) <=> !(t == v)
```

In English: either `t` has the value `v` ... or it doesn't.

---

<sup>1 - There is one exception to this.  If `T` is `float` or `double`, and you are comparing against the NaN value, then `==` always gives `false`, even if you are testing `NaN == NaN` !</sup>

Comment: So,I understood that if a variable is String,it can be null or it can be not null.There are no other possibility for String variable.

Comment: @cavadeveloper - A fruit is either a lemon or not a lemon.  An animal is either a cow, or it isn't a cow.

Answer (score 1):

Java have primitives and objects.

Primitives like **int** can not be null (they have big brothers though like **Integer** wrappers which actually can).

Talking about "nullness" of objects we're speaking abount reference variables or links to them. A link can be **not null if it references some object** or **null if it does not**. That's it, period, no other case.

Comment: Ok.There are no other possibility for reference variable.it's null or not null.I understood.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `IF .. ELSE IF .. ELSE` construct here since there is only two possibility `NULL` or `NOT NULL`. Simple `IF .. ELSE` construct would suffice. Better would be to use `Ternary Operator` like

```
string str = (abc == null) ? "IF" : "ELSE IF";
System.out.println(str);
```

(OR)

```
System.out.println((abc == null) ? "IF" : "ELSE IF");
```

Comment: @Thilo, yes missed that but that ternary condition can directly be added console print.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if..else` instead of `if...else if...else`. You have only two possibilities.

```
String abc=null;

if(abc==null){
   System.out.println("IF");
}else{
   System.out.println("ELSE");
}
```